# What was the original intent for the creation of Lambda calculus?

Tags: lo.logic, big-picture, lambda-calculus, ho.history-overview

I've read that initially Church proposed the $\lambda$-calculus as part of his *Postulates of Logic* paper (which is a dense read). But Kleene proved his "system" inconsistent after which, Church extracted relevant things for his work on "effective computability" and abandoned his prior work on logic.

So as I understand it, the $\lambda$-system and its notations took form as part of *something* to do with logic. What was Church initially trying to achieve that he forked off from later? What were the initial reasons for creating $\lambda$-calculus?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

He wanted to create a formal system for the foundations of logic and mathematics that was simpler than Russell's type theory and Zermelo's set theory.

The basic idea was to add a constant $\Xi$ to the untyped lambda calculus (or combinatory logic) and interpret $XZ$ as expressing "$Z$ satisfies the predicate $X$" and $\Xi XY$ as expressing "$X\subseteq Y$". With rules expressing these intentions one can then interpret the ${\to}{\forall}$-fragment of intuitionistic predicate logic and unrestricted comprehension, the only problem being that by Curry's paradox, every $X$ is derivable.

See p. 7 of:

Cardone and Hindley, *History of Lambda-calculus and Combinatory Logic*, 2006:
http://www.users.waitrose.com/~hindley/SomePapers_PDFs/2006CarHin,HistlamRp.pdf

As well as the introduction to:

Barendregt, Bunder and Dekkers, *Systems of Illative Combinatory Logic Complete for First-Order Propositional and Predicate Calculus*, JSL 58-3 (1993):
http://ftp.cs.ru.nl/CompMath.Found/ICL1.ps

Comment: "The only problem being that by Curry's paradox, every $X$ is derivable" :) It might be useful to remind what curry's paradox is: Given that there exists a term $Y$ such that $YM=M(YM)$ for every $M$, one can then write $Y(\neg)$ which is a proposition $\phi$ such that $\phi\Leftrightarrow\neg\phi$, giving the same contradiction as for Russel's paradox. Non-termination is crucial here, which motivated the creation of *simply typed* $\lambda$-calculus, in which every term terminates.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this was part of the motivation for creating the lambda calculus, but the lambda calculus was used to resolve the [Entscheidungsproblem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entscheidungsproblem), posed by Hilbert in 1928.  Turing independently resolved the Entscheidungsproblem by introducing the Turing machine.

From the Wikipedia article on Entscheidungsproblem:

> In 1936, Alonzo Church and Alan Turing published independent papers[2]
>   showing that a general solution to the Entscheidungsproblem is
>   impossible, assuming that the intuitive notion of "effectively
>   calculable" is captured by the functions computable by a Turing
>   machine (or equivalently, by those expressible in the lambda
>   calculus).

Comment: That's the "aftermath" of having created Lambda calculus earlier. He just reused a critical part of it for providing a definition for effective calculability.